# UITableViewController loadView loaded nib but didn't get a UITableView.

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

When I run my iOS simulator, I get this error:

```
UITableViewController loadView loaded the I1u-ML-mqb-view-QFc-WC-CU4 nib but didn't get a UITableView.'
```

My code:

```
@interface IF2000 : UITableViewController
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *EnterCategory;

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *Tfield;

- (IBAction)Submit:(id)sender;

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableViewCell *EmptyCell;

@end
```

This is the only code that I have typed so far. If anyone knows how to solve this problem, I would appreciate the help. If I could get a general answer on how to solve this problem, that would be good as well.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: possible duplicate of [loaded the "ChatView" nib but didn't get a UITableView.'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5772777/loaded-the-chatview-nib-but-didnt-get-a-uitableview)

Comment: I had a similar problem trying to use UITableViewController and figured it out. I posted an answer over here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11221802/nib-but-didnt-get-a-uitableview    I hope it helps you and please vote if it does. Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

Your nib file contains a view other than a table view as the first object. When you try to load a `UITableViewController` with a nib, you must make sure to have a table view as the first object.

Comment: Should have been the accepted answer!  Thanks for this.